# Specman - BFM is created though it shouldn't

Tags: verification, uvm, specman

I have a BFM in my tx agent (without a sequence driver).

```
extend uart_tx_agent_u{
   uart_tx_monitor : TX uart_monitor_u is instance;
   uart_tx_scb: uart_tx_scoreboard_u is instance;
   when ACTIVE uart_tx_agent_u {
      uart_bfm : uart_tx_bfm_u is instance;
   };
};
```

When I run the test (I don't change the active_passive field) I can see that the uart_bfm was created (according messages which are printed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want to change the constraint from test to test? Either the agent is active and sends data to the DUT, or it is passive and only collects data sent from the DUT.

What people usually do is to define the agent as ACTIVE, so that it has a sequence driver and a BFM.

In the test files, you define the scenarios for the tests, by defining the sequences for this agent.

So in tests that you do not want to send any data to the DUT from this agent, set the sequence to do nothing -

```
extend MAIN my_seq {
    body() @drive.clock is only {
        // do nothing, this agent should not send data in this test
    };
};
```

If you really want to change the environment topology, and in some tests the agent is to be PASSIVE and in some to be ACTIVE, you can do this in the test file, by constraining the agent.

And this constraint has to be in the pre-run generation. 
Through the test - the agent is either ACTIVE or not. This cannot be change during the run. You cannot say "i start the test with a PASSIVE agent, but during the test i want to make it ACTIVE".

Answer (score 0):

If the bfm is instantiated, it must be that the uart_tx_agent_u is ACTIVE.

when you say you don not change it - maybe it was randomly set to ACTIVE?

Comment: if u don't change this field the default is PASSIVE

Comment: If the `active_passive` field itself is generatable, and you don't explicitly declare your agent as `PASSIVE uart_tx_agent_u` and don't explicitly constrain it to be `PASSIVE`, it will be generated to a random value, which might be `PASSIVE` or `ACTIVE`.

Comment: @Yuri Tsoglin -  so where I have to explicitly declare it? in the test or in the extend/decleration of the agent?

Comment: @Sara p
Depending on your needs. Either in the declaration - declare the instance field to be of type `PASSIVE uart_tx_agent_u` rather than just `uart_tx_agent_u` (if you consider it always to be PASSIVE, in all tests), or add a constraint in your test - `keep my_agent.active_passive == PASSIVE` (if it can be ACTIVE in some tests and PASSIVE in others).

Comment: @Yuri Tsoglin - I did the following: 1. In the env file I declare the agent: `unit uart_rx_agent_u like uvm_agent {
   keep soft active_passive == PASSIVE;   
};`          in the uart_rx_agent file I did the following: `extend uart_rx_agent_u{
   uart_rx_monitor : RX uart_monitor_u is instance;
   when ACTIVE uart_rx_agent_u
   {
      uart_bfm : uart_rx_bfm_u is instance;
      driver: uart_driver_u is instance;
   };   
};'
 In the test I wrote the following constraint in one of my sequence:  `   keep uart_env.uart_rx_agent.active_passive == ACTIVE; ` Yet the BFM was not created.

Answer (score 0):

a sequence struct is being generated after the test starts. and a sequence is generated only if there is a driver. and a driver is instantiated only if the agent is ACTIVE. 
environment topology should be constrained top down, not to constrain a unit from a struct that is contained in it

if you know you want to agent to be ACTIVE, then constrain it -

```
extend rx_uart_agent_u {
    keep active_passive == TRUE;
};
```

or from its parent

```
extend env {
    keep me.rx_agent.active_passive == TRUE;
};
```

Comment: but if I want that in some test it will be ACTIVE, and in others PASSIVE?

Comment: you can put the constraint in a test file, but not inside a sequence.

Comment: But how can I change the constraint from test to test?